# Young Diagrams and distinguishing between two distributions

Tags: ds.algorithms, pr.probability, polynomial-time, oracles

**Introduction**:

The reference for everything is [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00034.pdf) paper.

> The Robinson–Schensted–Knuth (RSK) algorithm is a well-known
> combinatorial algorithm with diverse applications throughout
> mathematics, computer science, and physics. Given a word $w$ with $n$
> letters from the alphabet $[d]$, it outputs two semistandard Young
> tableaus $(\text{P}, \text{Q}) = \text{RSK}(w)$ with common shape
> given by some Young diagram $\lambda \in \mathbb{N}^{d}$ $(\lambda_1
>  \geq \cdots \geq λ_d)$. We write $λ = \text{shRSK}(w).$
>
> Given a probability distribution $\alpha = (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_d)$ on
> alphabet $[d]$, an $n$-letter $\alpha$-random word $w = (w_1, \cdots, 
>  w_n)$, written as $w \sim \alpha^{\otimes n}$, is a random word in
> which each letter $w_i$ is independently drawn from $[d]$ according to
> $\alpha$. The Schur–Weyl distribution $\text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)$ is the
> distribution on Young diagrams given by $\lambda = \text{shRSK}(w)$.

Let the length of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of a Young diagram be $\lambda_i$, for $i \in [d]$. From the paper referenced (Theorem $1.4$):

> For $k ∈ [d]$, set $ν_k = \text{min}\{1, α_k d\}$. Then,
> $$α_kn−2\sqrt{ν_k n}  \leq \underset{{\lambda \sim
>  \text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)}}{\mathbb{E}}[\lambda_k]\leq α_kn +2\sqrt{ν_k n} 
>  .$$

From Proposition $4.8$,

> Let $\alpha \in [d]$ be a probability distribution. Then for any $k \in
>  [d]$, $$\underset{{\lambda \sim
>  \text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)}}{\text{Var}} \left[λ_k\right] \leq16n.$$

Note that $n$ is the total length of all the rows of the Young diagram. That is
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{d} \lambda_i = n.$$

If $n$ is much smaller than $d$, many of the rows may have a length of $0$.

---

**The problem**:

Let two probability distributions, on alphabet $[2^{m}]$, be $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Both of them are efficiently samplable.

It is known that

$$\alpha_i = \frac{1}{2^{m}},$$

for every $i \in [2^{m}]$, and

$$\beta_i = \frac{1}{2^{m/2}},$$
for every $i \in [2^{m/2}]$ and $0$ otherwise.

**Input**: For an $n = \text{poly}(m)$, we are either given a Young diagram $\lambda$ sampled from $\text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)$ or a Young diagram sampled from $\text{SW}^{n}(\beta)$.

**Task**: We want to distinguish between the two cases (in other words, tell which distribution the Young diagram came from.)

Is there a polynomial-time uniform classical distinguishing algorithm that distinguishes between these two cases?

---

My intuition is that there should exist no such distinguisher. Since $n = \text{poly}(m)$, the useful "signal" we get after looking at the length of each row of the Young diagram is inverse exponentially small --- whereas the "noise" is inverse polynomially large. Thus, the two cases would look exactly similar to any distinguisher.

Is there a statistical or a computational argument that makes this formal?

Comment: 1. You have a typo in your statement of Theorem 1.4, the square roots should include the n. 2. Forget about computational efficiency, unless I am missing something the answer is "it's information theoretically impossible." You need n to be $\Omega(2^{m/2})$ to distinguish uniform from "uniform on a random half of the support" by a birthday paradox. Since the distribution of the tableau only depends on the *sorted* probability vector (see Definition 1.3) your setting is equivalent to getting $\lambda$ in the latter case. So for $n=$poly$(m)$, you can't information-theoretically distinguish.

Comment: @ClementC. Might you develop your comment into an answer?

Comment: @ClementC. I had a few questions. 1. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are "uniform and uniform on a random half of the support." So, if we are given samples from $\alpha$ or $\beta$, it is true that we cannot distinguish between them without at least a sub-exponential number of samples. However, we are not sampling from $\alpha$ or $\beta$. We are sampling from $\text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)$ and $\text{SW}^{n}(\beta)$ ---  $\text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)$  is the Plancherel distribution (see last line of page 1 of the paper) and I do not know what distribution $\text{SW}^{n}(\beta)$ is.

Comment: So, the two settings do not seem exactly similar

Comment: @ClementC. Also, the Young diagram encodes not just a value but also a particular shape (looking at the length of its rows allows us to calculate the $n$ largest $\alpha_i$s or $\beta_i$s to very bad accuracy). That is, not only are we given samples from $\text{SW}^{n}(\alpha)$ and  $\text{SW}^{n}(\beta)$, we also are given $n = \text{poly}(m)$ largest probability values (upto a very bad accuracy) from either $\alpha$ or  $\beta$. In light of all this additional information, I am not sure how to directly port the bounds from traditional distribution testing settings.

Comment: @AngryLion I expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even relaxing the "computationally efficient" requirement, it is information-theoretically impossible. We will use the following "folklore" fact, which can be viewed as a consequence of the birthday paradox:

**Fact.** Distinguishing with probability say $2/3$ between (1) the uniform distribution on $[d]$ and (2) a distribution on a subset of half the domain $[d]$, chosen uniformly at random, requires $n=\Omega(\sqrt{d})$ samples.

Let's call this problem $(\star)$. In our case, $d=2^m$, but note that the problem we want to solve is *not* an instance of $(\star)$: $\alpha$ is indeed the uniform distribution on $d$, but $\beta$ is a uniform distribution on a very specific, known subset of $d/2$ elements, and so the fact stating hardness of $(\star)$ does not apply directly *(it's actually very easy to distinguish between the two with $O(1)$ samples!)*. But we also don't directly have access to the sequence of $n$ samples $w$, we only have access to them through $\lambda := \mathrm{shRSK}(w)$. So, well, it *does* apply. Let's see why.

From Definition 1.3 of [[O'Donnell–Wright'16]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00034):

> The Schur–Weyl distribution $\mathrm{SW}^n(\alpha)$ is the distribution on Young diagrams given by $\lambda := \mathrm{shRSK}(w)$ [when $w\sim \alpha^{\otimes n}$]. Although it is not obvious, it is a fact
> that the distribution $\mathrm{SW}^n(\alpha)$ does not depend on the ordering of $\alpha$'s components.

What this means (if I am reading this correctly) is that $\mathrm{SW}^n(\alpha)$ only depends on the multiset of frequencies of $\alpha$, not on the labeling of the domain. In particular, all "uniform distributions on a subset of half the domain" lead  to the same distribution $\mathrm{SW}^n$ over $\lambda$.

Which is exactly what we need to conclude. Suppose by contradiction we had an algorithm (even inefficient!) which distinguishes $\mathrm{SW}^n(\alpha)$ from $\mathrm{SW}^n(\beta)$ with probability at least $2/3$, given $\lambda$ from either of the two distributions (where $n = o(2^{m/2})$, i.e., $n=o(\sqrt{d})$). Then we could use it to solve $(\star)$ as follows: given $n$ samples (i.e., a word $w$) from an instance of $(\star)$, we compute $\lambda = \mathrm{shRSK}(w)$, and feed it into our purported algorithm. But the $\lambda$ is then either from $\mathrm{SW}^n(\alpha)$ or $\mathrm{SW}^n(\beta)$, so the algorithm can distinguish. This allows us to solve $(\star)$ with way too few samples, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: If I misunderstood something (the whole argument relies on my understanding of Definition 1.3 of [OW16]), please let me know.